# Pyrogram does not work (does not run) on the server

Tags: python, pyrogram

I encountered the problem of program execution freezing while calling the run method of pyrogram library. This is the first time I've encountered something like this, no errors, no hints about what is needed.

Configuration: ubuntu 18.04.6; Python3.10.13 installed from source; Server rebooted after python installation; Pyrogram library latest version; TgCrypto also installed; Python has internet access (sends requests through queries normally).

On the local machine it works fine, but on the server it doesn't. Help solve the problem, who has encountered similar problems, because I've already run out of ideas. Preferably without rebooting the server, but if it is necessary, then write about it.

Installed different versions of python from 3.10 to 3.11.4. I expected the run method to work fine or give any errors, but the problem remains the same, run hangs, no logs, no login data requested.

Tried updating ubuntu packages, but that didn't help either.

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer this without a [mcve]

Comment: Check firewall/security groups on the server, verify correct API credentials, and ensure proxy (if any) is configured properly. Add debug logs in your script (e.g., print statements) to understand where execution hangs. Use `dmesg` and `journalctl` to view server system logs. Consider a new virtual environment on the server and reinstall required packages. As a last resort, backup important data and try rebooting the server.

Comment: If the issue seems more related to the server environment or Linux configuration rather than the Pyrogram library, you can consider asking for help on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). These platforms have active communities with expertise in server and Linux-related issues and could provide insights.